# How do properly setup the textures in a startup.blend file

Tags: materials

I am trying to setup a new template with a startup.blend

The way we have set up our directories, the only way to guarantee textures will load properly is by using relative paths.

Since the new file created based on this template won't have been saved yet, the relative paths break.

Is there a recommended way to included textures in a startup.blend file?

Thanks,
Koen

Comment: Is this something you can go to File -> External Data -> and pack it into the .blend?

Comment: Hello Allen, thanks for that answer, that’s what I ended up doing. The one downside is that my file went from 1mb to 50 mb as it includes a large environment exr. All the files derived from this startup will now carry this load as well. Still experimenting with more elegant solutions. Cheers, koe n

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

These can point to nonexistent locations, maybe it's a jumping off point for you.